# Remove value of input using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to remove some values from a hidden and text input box using jQuery, but somehow this is not working

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" value="abc" name="ht1" id="ht1" />
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" />
```

I use the following jQuery code to remove the values with an onclick event

```
$('#rt1').click(function() {
    $('#t1').val();  
    $('#ht1').val();  
});
```

Can I empty the contents of the input box and clear the value of the hidden field using jQuery?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$('#rt1').click(function() {
    $('#t1').attr('value', '');  
    $('#ht1').attr('value', '');  
});
```

Comment: Also you can shorten to $('#t1, #ht1').attr('value', '');

Answer (score 43):

You should do this:

```
$('#rt1').click(function() {
    $('#t1').val('');  
    $('#ht1').val('');  
});
```

That is, pass an empty string. Either that, or use removeAttr (`query.removeAttr('value')`).

Comment: +1, Seconded, I would say removeAttr() is the preferred way to do this.

Comment: Note that the attribute is NOT removed with `.val('')`, so if you have dependencies checking for the existence of the attribute (not the value), you do need to run `removeAttr`. (In my code I had dependencies on both, so I even had to run `query.val('').change().removeAttr('value')`).

Answer (score 8):

Shorter version

```
$('#rt1').click(function() {
    $('#t1, #ht1').val('');  
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to pass an empty string in the `val()` function or, you can use the more generic `attr()` function that sets a given attribute to a given value:

```
$('#rt1').click(function() {
    $('#t1').attr("value", "");  
    $('#ht1').attr("value", "");  
});
```

Comment: This should work but in my case I don't know y it is not working so I used $('#t1').val(). It works fine for me. I don't why in my case .attr is not working. If any one explain this then it is good for us.

Answer (score 2):

This should be:

```
$('#rt1').click(function() {
    $('#t1').val('');  
    $('#ht1').val('');  
});
```

When val() function doesn't have parameter it will serves as getter not setter

Comment: $('#t1').attr("value", ""); why this is not working for me, same place ur code is working. Can u explain please.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $('input').click(function(){ 

    $(this).removeAttr('value');

  });
});

//remove value when click

//without effect input type  submit 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $('input:not(:submit)').click(function(){ 

    $(this).removeAttr('value');
  });
});
```